# Can Install4j make a multi-platform Java application run on system startup?

Tags: install4j

I am looking at options on how to make a multi-platform Java application run on system startup. There are obviously ways to do it manually for any application (e.g., ["How to Make a Program Run at Startup on Any Computer"](https://www.howtogeek.com/228467/how-to-make-a-program-run-at-startup-on-any-computer/)). Unfortunately, they are all different and depend on the operating system version and Linux distribution. I need to support at least:

- Windows >= 7
- macOS >= 10.12
- Ubuntu >= 16.04
- Raspbian >= 8

It would be awesome if Install4j already has a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a "Add a startup executable on Windows and macOS" action in install4j.

On Linux/Unix there is no general solution for this problem, so you have to do it yourself for the particular environments that you want to support.